# Confusion on the definition of spectral integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory

I'm following this [text](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/RaskinSam.pdf)

Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$ be the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, and $P(\mathcal{H})$ the set of projections on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, denoting by 1 and 0 the projections $p\in P(\mathcal{H})$ which project to $\mathcal{H}$ and the set $\{0\}$, respectively.

A complex espectral measure is a function $E:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})\to P(\mathcal{H})$ such that:

1. $E(\emptyset)=0$ and $E(\mathbb{C})=1$,
2. If $\{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of disjoint Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, then $E(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E(B_n)$.

Everything good up to here for me. My problem is that all of a sudden the notation is changed to $E_\lambda=E(\lambda)$.

Now, given an spectral measure $E$, one defines the spectral integral with respect to $v,w\in\mathcal{H}$ of the measurable function $f$ as the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral $\int f(\lambda)d\langle E_\lambda v,w\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product in $\mathcal{H}$.

What is $\lambda$ supposed to represent? For me is weird to denote a Borel set with $\lambda$, but since that's the domain of $E$, I guess that's ok. But when I try to understand the integral, everything looks blurred. My only idea is that maybe $E_\lambda=E(\{\lambda\})$, is that so? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Same integration with respect to a measure. $\int f(\lambda)d\mu(\lambda)$, where $\mu$ is a measure on some space. In this case, the measures $\mu_{u,v}(S)$ depend on two vectors $u,v$, which allows the measure to be represented as the form of an operator $\mu_{u,v}(S)=\langle E(S)u,v\rangle$. So the individual measures lift to an operator $E=E(S)$ that is a function of a Borel set $S$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts So $f$ has $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$ as domain?

Comment: $f$ is a complex function of a complex variable. The functions $\mu_{u,v}$ and $E$ are defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. $\mu_{u,v}$ is a complex measure defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. So $\int f d_{u,v}$ is an integral of a complex function $f$ with respect to a complex measure $\mu_{u,v}$ defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.